# connecting videos?

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I'm running Windows 7 and I surprisingly can't find a free video editor which will allow me to "merge" video files shot by a GoPro into 1 video file and slice it from the beginning and end. There seem to be several programs for Linux and Mac, but I can't find anything which will do the job on Windows.
I've tried Blender but its very slow for video editing (my video is 3 hours long).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (and Linux/Mac)
- [Concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7333232/395857) two files for most video formats.
- Fast.
- Is CLI.